# Passing Malloc char pointer to function

Tags: c

When I try to pass a `malloc`'d char pointer from `main` to use in `user_input` to get a string in it. After the while loop is done I'm trying to print `filename`. `filename` ends up to be empty when it should contain a valid string.

```
void user_input(char *filename){
    char ch;

    int i = 0;

    printf("Fil att leta i: ");
    while((ch = getchar()) == '\n'){
        filename = realloc(filename, (i+1) * sizeof(char));
        filename[i] = ch;

        i++;
    }
    filename[i] = '\0';
    printf("filnamn = %s", filename);

}

int main(void){
    char *filename;

    filename = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    user_input(filename);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know, `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1. There's absolutely no reason to ask whether a `char` is more than one `char` big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filename` is a pointer which is passed by value. When you do this in the `user_input` function

```
filename = realloc(filename, (i+1) * sizeof(char));
```

the `filename` in the `main` does not change. When you print `filename` in the `main`, the pointer has been realloced, so you trigger undefined behavior.

You need to pass `filename` by pointer. Since it's already a pointer, you end up with a double pointer:

```
void user_input(char **filenamePtr)
```

Now you need to take a pointer in the `main`

```
user_input(&filename);
```

and dereference in the `user_input`:

```
*filenamePtr = realloc(*filenamePtr, i+2);
```

Note that `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, so you do not need to multiply by it. Also you add 2, not 1, to `i` so that you have enough space for the null terminator `'\0'` character.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
while((ch = getchar()) == '\n')
```

into this:

```
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
```

you *only* read the `\n`. You should read anything *but* the `\n`.